# Large Strings taking forever to 'create'

Tags: vb.net, binary, hex

I have a program which loads the bites of a file in to a hexadecimal array, the resulting length of the array is 16,777,216. I perform a few quick edits to the array, convert it in to one giant string (length is 33,554,432) so that this can be converted back in to a byte array and written to a new file.. well, I try to.

The issue is that the string is taking forever to be created, even after minutes (which is all I'd expect it to take) of waiting. I don't think there's a better way of setting up this string like I currently have it, but is there a way I can accomplish this by keeping the hex array as-is? Or would there be a simple way for me to only modify the offsets I need to without re-writing the entire file?

```
 Dim tHex As String = ""
 For i = 0 To gloBytes.Length - 1
     tHex &= gloBytes(i)
 Next
```

Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: you're itereating over every byte in the file, and then building the converted string character-by-character... no wonder it's slow... 16 million conversions + 16 million string concatentations...

Comment: @MarcB - And each of those concatenations has to create a new string and copy the data from the old string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're going to be doing lots of manipulations to a string, you should use a [`StringBuilder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.aspx) instead of directly appending to the `String`.

Since `System.String` is immutable, each time you do `tHex &= gloBytes(i)`, you're creating an entirely new string.  This causes a huge amount of memory churn, and puts lots of pressure on the GC, which in turn causes the entire thing to be very slow.

`StringBuilder`, on the other hand, is designed to allow you to append to a "string" many times and not churn memory, as it's a mutable class designed specifically to allow multiple operations to be performed, and then converted to a string (via `ToString()`) once at the end.

The equivelent code using `StringBuilder` would be:

```
Dim tmp as New StringBuilder(gloBytes.Length * 2)
For i = 0 To gloBytes.Length - 1
    tmp.Append(gloBytes(i))
Next
Dim tHex As String = tmp.ToString()
```

Comment: Thanks for making me feel a little bit stupid!
But in all seriousness, thanks. Not sure why I didn't think of that before.